# How to properly scale imported image to fit ImageView?

Tags: android, image, imageview, uri, scaling

In my application I am importing and displaying many images. To set img uri I am using `Img.setImageUri(R.mipmap.myimage)` But the result is making image croped in device determined way for example on my phone i have square app icons and layout looks like this

[image]

so it's square shaped and on emulator which has circular icons it looks like this

[image]

so it's in shape of circle

What i want is to resize images to fit image views
Images are stored as uri in database so i NEED to get result based on that.

my xml for it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:id="@+id/foodlay"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        app:cardElevation="10dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:id="@+id/imago"
            android:background="@null"
            />

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

In code i just use `Img.setImageUri(cursor.getString(6))` in adapter

Answer (score 1):

i suggest to you use ShapeableImageView instead of this way, however if you want use your solution replace this

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

property instead of centerInside